# Race condition caused by cursors persisted to temp files - is it possible

Tags: race-condition, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm troubleshooting a problem with a Visual Fox Pro application (built with the Visual Fox Express framework) which I suspect is being caused by a race condition. The application is being hosted on a Citrix XenApp server and under certain conditions, data displayed on a certain form appears to be incorrect, and changes to something other than what the user is entering.

The form in question displays a list of records returned from a query on a SQL Server database based on certain information entered by the user.

If this is what is happening I suspect the sequence of events is something like this:

> 1) User 1 enters data and causes form to dispay grid of data of
>   results returned from database.
>
> 2) User 2 opens same form on different Citrix session and enters data
>   causing form to display a grid data of results returned from database.
>   This cursor gets persisted to disk and overwrites, or somehow
>   conflicts with User 1's cursor for that form.
>
> 3) Some FoxPro cursor mechanism on User 1's instance sees changed data
>   in the cursor (from User 2) and updates the screen with data from the
>   cursor.

I don't know much about how FoxPro works but from what I understand in some circumstances a cursor will be persisted to a temp file. On our Citrix application server this temp folder may be shared by between 10 and 50 users. I'm looking for information about if a race condition caused by a cursor written to a file in the temp folder is something that is even possible so that I can continue researching down that path or rule it out definitively.

I know there are ways to make it so that the FoxPro temp files are written to a different folder for each user and I am working on making the change to do that but I would like to find out if anyone else has seen a similar problem or thinks that what I suspect is actually possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT does sound strange, but yes, Foxpro creates temp tables of cursors it uses for display and query results, such as local or remote data access.  However, when created, they are created as read-only or read-write, but ONLY for the person per connection.  When a cursor attempts to be created, it generates a random file name for the results and uses that as the .dbf cursor for presenting to the user.

COULD IT be a racing issue?  I doubt that, but not knowing specifics of the quite old Visual FoxExpress framework, don't know what/where you would configure to have it dynamically use a different location of temp files.  It should be going to the temp files path of the Windows environment variables.  So, if users of the Citrix connection are using the same user / password for multiple sessions, yes, it would go to the same location, but when trying to generate the temp file, it would fail getting an exclusive handle and try again with the next random file name.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say very unlikely that temp files are implicated here. Each cursor you create uses a different temp file; I don't see how two users, even in a Citrix-type situation, would share a single temp file.